# Tool for ls -R in git repos

Tags: git, unix, ls

I've been using `ls -R` as a convenient way to peek at the structure and contents of small-medium sized directories, such as projects I'm working on, but it's become difficult to use because of the presence of `.git` in many of them.

When there's a `.git` the first ~100 lines of `ls -R` are just a huge list of git index files and hashes, making it very difficult to use. Is there a way I can modify `ls -R` or another tool I can use to make it only show me files outside of `.git`? Preferably, I'd still be able to see other dotfile folders, but I'd survive if I couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the `-I` (or `--ignore`) option of ls: `ls -R -I .git`

Take a look at the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Which-files-are-listed.html#Which-files-are-listed):

```
‘-I pattern’
‘--ignore=pattern’
    In directories, ignore files whose names match the shell pattern (not regular
    expression) pattern. As in the shell, an initial ‘.’ in a file name does not
    match a wildcard at the start of pattern. Sometimes it is useful to give this
    option several times. For example,

        $ ls --ignore='.??*' --ignore='.[^.]' --ignore='#*'

    The first option ignores names of length 3 or more that start with ‘.’, the
    second ignores all two-character names that start with ‘.’ except ‘..’, and
    the third ignores names that start with ‘#’.
```

Comment: `ls -R -I .git` doesn't work for me. It throws `ls: illegal option -- I`.

Comment: @sortfiend Which operating system are you using? I see that you used the `unix` tag in your question, but unix exists in many variants.

Comment: I have OS X Mavericks

Comment: @sortfiend OS X is based on BSD and indeed its [ls](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html) command has not any `-I` option. The excerpt I used in my answer is from the manual of GNU `ls` which command is by default not available on OS X. However you can install and use it. See [Install and Use GNU Command Line Tools on Mac OS X](http://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/)

Answer (score 1):

Git's `ls-files` has useful options.  Plain `git ls-files` will list only tracked files.  Use `git ls-files -oc` to list everything.

```
git ls-files -ic --exclude-standard
```

lists all tracked files that match a `.gitignore` pattern, it's good to know about those.

---

Asking it to show only "ignored" files while feeding it custom ignore patterns can be very useful:

```
git ls-files -ic -x*.pdf
```

will show you all tracked .pdf's, s/ic/io/ to get untracked .pdfs, etc.  [Check out its docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-files.html), you can [ab]use its exclude variations in all sorts of useful ways.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility might be to use [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

```
find . -path ./.git -prune -o -print
```